# how to validate an accesstoken and facebook id?

Tags: django, facebook, tastypie

I'm building an ios app which uses Django as server. Users login my server use their facebook account. ios app get facebook id and access token first, then I want to send facebook id and access token to my server to validate it. If the facebook id and access token is correct, server will create a user.

My question is :

how to validate facebook id and access token? 
e.g. a user whose facebook id is 123 get an accessToken: abc in app, then the app send the info to my server,  how can server validate that the accessToken abc is assigned for 123, not for other facebook id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify an access_token, make a call to the `https://graph.facebook.com/me` endpoint with it. Then use the retrieved data to validate the user's id.